# Close and Change Status buttons missing for some users on in Case List View

Tags: permissions

I've noticed that some of our users cannot see the *Close* or *Change Status* buttons which normally appear in the cases List Views. They have permissions to read, create and edit cases.

What I can see:
[image: What a Sys Admin can see]

What they can see:
[image]

I have checked in the search layouts that all the buttons are available (this was unnecessary because they are all appearing to me as a system administrator).

These users should only be able to see cases of a certain record type, so I don't want to override any sharing rules that rules that we've created (Organization Wide Default = private for cases).

Grateful for any help on how to get these buttons to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the buttons were not appearing to some profiles was that those profiles needed the 'Manage Cases' permission.

Unfortunately, the 'Manage Cases' permission needs the users to have read, create, edit **and delete** permissions for that object and I don't want these users to have delete permissions.

Comment: Can you try with permission sets maybe?

Comment: @Saariko - Whether I give them the permission by permission set or by normal object permission has the same effect. They still will not be able have the 'Manage Cases' permission without having the *delete* permission for cases and I don't want them to have that.

Comment: We struggled with the same thing. Ended up granting the "Manage Cases" permission, and then have a very simple trigger on the Case Object to prevent deletion..

Comment: @Mikey - Cheers. Yes a work colleague suggested that to me, but that means having the `del` links on the page. My colleague then also suggested that we could implement a custom button to add to the List View that could close the case. The problem with that is that you can really only set the status to a single value unless you implement a VisualForce page. Swings and roundabouts really.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Org wide sharing rule as private only - I think your only option will be to add a manual sharing rule.

You could set the sharing rule to be based on it's type:

On the rule creation, select: Based on criteria. and set the record type of the object:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I might have phrased the question badly, but I have already set up the sharing rule so that members of a certain team can see each others' cases. My issue is simply that some people can't see the Close and Change Status buttons in the cases list view. I just mentioned sharing because I wanted to make sure that any solution didn't override the sharing settings that I have in place.

Comment: Does the sharing rule permit editing cases owned by others?

Comment: @MikeChale If you give it read/write than yea, that's the idea of the sharing.

Comment: @Mike - Yes it does Mike.